# Flutter - Not loading full design in ios device

Tags: ios, flutter

I am developing new application in flutter. This application works well in android simulator, android real device and in iOS simulator. In iOS real device application works well in first launch but when i restart the app it shows only the textfield. Please help me to solve this issue.

[image: This is the screen displayed when I run the application]

[image: Expected Output]

main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:moonlight/screens/sign_in.dart';

void main() {
   WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
   SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
   DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
   DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
 ]);
 runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

// This widget is the root of your application.
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  title: 'Moonlight',
    theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: 'Prata'),
  home: SignInScreen(),
  );
 }
}
```

sign_in.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:moonlight/screens/sign_up.dart';
import 'package:moonlight/utils/constants.dart';
import 'package:moonlight/widget/textButton.dart';
import 'package:moonlight/widget/textFiled.dart';

import '../services/dimensions.dart';

class SignInScreen extends StatefulWidget {
const SignInScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
State<SignInScreen> createState() => _SignInScreenState();
}

class _SignInScreenState extends State<SignInScreen> {


final TextEditingController emailController = new 
TextEditingController();
final TextEditingController passwordController = new 
TextEditingController();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
  appBar: PreferredSize(
      preferredSize: 
  Size.fromHeight(Dimensions().getResponsiveSize(170)),
      child: Container(
        color: appBarColor,
        child: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: appBarColor,
          toolbarHeight: Dimensions().getResponsiveSize(170),
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                //color: Colors.red,
                width: Dimensions().getResponsiveSize(200),
                height: Dimensions().getResponsiveSize(40),
                //width: 200,
                //color: Colors.red,

                child: Image.asset(
                  logoUrl,
                  fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                  //height: Dimensions().getResponsiveSize(50),
                  //width: Dimensions().getResponsiveSize(200),
                  //width: 50,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 
    Dimensions().getResponsiveSize(20),),
              Text('Sign In',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: Dimensions().getResponsiveSize(25),
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
              ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: Dimensions().getResponsiveSize(5),),
              Text('Welcome',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: Dimensions().getResponsiveSize(15),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )),
    bottomNavigationBar: GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
  
    },
    child: Container(
      color: appBarColor,
      height: Dimensions().getResponsiveSize(50),
      child: Center(
          child: Text(
        'Go',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 
     Dimensions().getResponsiveSize(15),
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
        ),
      )),
    ),
  ),
  body: Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 
    Dimensions().getResponsiveSize(20)),
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        TextFieldInput(
          controller: emailController,
          icon: Icons.email,
          text: 'Email',
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: Dimensions().getResponsiveSize(10),
        ),
        TextFieldInput(
          controller: passwordController,
          icon: Icons.lock_rounded,
          text: 'Password',
          isObscure: true,
        ),
        Row(
          children: [
            Spacer(),
            TextButtonWidget(
              onPressed:forgotPassword,
              text: 'Forgot Password?',
              size: Dimensions().getResponsiveSize(15),
              color: appBarColor,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: Dimensions().getResponsiveSize(20),
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.grey,
              width: Dimensions().getResponsiveSize(70),
              height: 1.2,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: Dimensions().getResponsiveSize(10),
            ),
            Text(
              'OR',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey,
              fontSize: Dimensions().getResponsiveSize(15)
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: Dimensions().getResponsiveSize(10),
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.grey,
              width: Dimensions().getResponsiveSize(70),
              height: 1.2,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: Dimensions().getResponsiveSize(20),
        ),
        TextButtonWidget(
          onPressed: signUpScreen,
          text: 'Sign Up',
          size: Dimensions().getResponsiveSize(15),
          color: appBarColor,
        ),
      ],
    ),
   ),
   );
  }

  forgotPassword(){
  
 }

 signUpScreen(){
 Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SignUpScreen()),
 );
 }
 }
```

dimensions.dart

```
 import 'package:get/get.dart';

 class Dimensions{
  static double shortestSide = Get.size.shortestSide;

   getResponsiveSize(dynamic size) {

   dynamic x = (size/392.72727272727275) * 100;

    return (shortestSide*x)/100;

   }

   }
```

Comment: Please include codes

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy-paste a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so others can reproduce it to find an answer for you.